# How to print the address an ada access variable points to?

Tags: ada

I want to print the address of an access variable (pointer) for debugging purposes.

```
type Node is private;
type Node_Ptr is access Node;

procedure foo(n: in out Node_Ptr) is
    package Address_Node is new System.Address_To_Access_Conversions(Node);
    use Address_Node;
begin
    Put_Line("node at address " & System.Address_Image(To_Address(n)));
end foo;
```

Address_Image returns the string representation of an address.
System.Address_To_Access_Conversions is a generic package to convert between addresses and access types (see [ARM 13.7.2](http://www.adaic.org/standards/1zrm/html/RM-13-7-2.html)), defined as follows:

```
generic
    type Object(<>) is limited private;
package System.Address_To_Access_Conversions is
   -- [...]
   type Object_Pointer is access all Object;
   -- [...]
   function To_Address(Value : Object_Pointer) return Address;
   -- [...]
end System.Address_To_Access_Conversions;
```

gnat gives me the following errors for procedure foo defined above:

```
expected type "System.Address_To_Access_Conversions.Object_Pointer" from instance at line...
found type "Node_Ptr" defined at ...
```

Object_Pointer ist definied as access all Object. From my understanding the type Object is Node, therefore Object_Ptr is access all Node. What is gnat complaining about?
I guess my understanding of Ada generics is flawed and I am not using System.Address_To_Access_Conversions correctly.

EDIT:
I compiled my code with "gnatmake -gnatG" to see the generic instantiation:

```
package address_node is
    subtype btree__clear__address_node__object__2 is btree__node;
    type btree__clear__address_node__object_pointer__2 is access
        all btree__clear__address_node__object__2;
    function to_address (value :
        btree__clear__address_node__object_pointer__2) return
        system__address;
end address_node;
```

btree__node is the mangled name of the type Node as defined above, so I really think the parameter type for to_address() is correct, yet gnat is complaining (see above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a compiler in front of me at the moment, but doesn't this work?

```
procedure foo(n: in out Node_Ptr) is 
begin 
   Put_Line("node at address " & System.Address_Image(n.all'address)); --'
end foo;
```

Comment: Yes, it does. I didn't find anything on explicit dereferencing of access variables, so I assumed that there is no such thing in Ada. I know better now, thanks!

Comment: You can also do a `'access` to get a pointer, which is a smidge more useful. You really shouldn't be doing either in Ada except in some very rare circumstances though. I suggest you go to appendix K (Language-defined Attributes) of your friendly neighborhood Ada LRM and read clean through it. There's lots of good stuff in there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, explicit type conversion does the trick:

```
procedure Foo(n: in out Node_Ptr) is
    package Address_Node is new System.Address_To_Access_Conversions(Node);
    use Address_Node;
    p : Address_Node.Object_Pointer;
begin
    p := Address_Node.Object_Pointer(n);
    Put_Line("node at address " & System.Address_Image(To_Address(p)));
end Foo;
```

Takes some time getting used to Ada... ;-)